# check last character of command output

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
ip="172.16.0.28"
community="abcd"

currentState=$(snmpget -v 1 -Oe -c $community $ip PowerNet-MIB::sPDUOutletCtl.$1)
currentState="${currentState: -1}"
if [ $currentState == 2 ] ; then
    snmpset -v 1 -c abcd 172.16.0.28 PowerNet-MIB::sPDUOutletCtl.$1 i outletOn
else
    snmpset -v 1 -c abcd 172.16.0.28 PowerNet-MIB::sPDUOutletCtl.$1 i outletOff
fi
```

Is it possible to rewrite the if statement as an one liner?

Something like

```
echo "${$(snmpget -v 1 -Oe -c abcd 172.16.0.28 PowerNet-MIB::sPDUOutletCtl.1): -1}"

bash: ${$(snmpget -v 1 -Oe -c abcd 172.16.0.28 PowerNet-MIB::sPDUOutletCtl.1): -1}: bad substitution
```

does not work.

EDIT: As requested, a possible return of snmpget:

```
$ snmpget -v 1 -Oe -c abcd 172.16.0.28 PowerNet-MIB::sPDUOutletCtl.1
PowerNet-MIB::sPDUOutletCtl.1 = INTEGER: 1
```

Comment: please update the question with an example of what's in the `currentState' variable

Comment: `[[ $(yourCommand) = *2 ]]`, if you want to check if the output ends with `2` (in a bash-only way; adding an answer describing the portable-to-all-POSIX-shells approach).

Comment: Your question is confusing. First you ask about rewriting the `if` statement, but then your attempt are about rewriting the variable assignments.

Comment: BTW, note that `==` shouldn't be used in `[` (which is another name for the `test` command). The only [standard-compliant](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) string comparison operator is `=`, not `==`; bash allows `==` as an extension, but using it means your code won't work with other shells (like ash or dash).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In code compatible with all POSIX-compliant shells:

```
case "$(snmpget -v 1 -Oe -c "$community" "$ip" "PowerNet-MIB::sPDUOutletCtl.$1")" in
  *2) sfx=On;;  # output from snmpget ends with 2
  *)  sfx=Off;; # output from snmpget does not end with 2
esac
```

Comment: The bash specfic analog is `if [[ "$(snmpget ...)" == *2 ]]; then ...` -- the key here is that `==` within `[[...]]` is a _pattern matching_ operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the parameter expansion operators like this, they only operate on parameters (i.e. variables).

You can pipe to the `tail` command to get the last character of output.

```
currentState="$(snmpget -v 1 -Oe -c abcd 172.16.0.28 PowerNet-MIB::sPDUOutletCtl.1 | tail -c 2)"
```

You need to use `-c 2` because the last character is a newline, and you want the character before that. The command substitution will then discard the newline at the end of the `tail` output.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- `currentState` ends in a character that's expected to be a number (or at least if the last character is `2` then the `snmpget` call should end with `...On`)
- the objective is to determine if the last `snmpset` arg should end with `..On` or `..Off`

One idea:

```
ip="172.16.0.28"
community="abcd"

currentState=$(snmpget -v 1 -Oe -c $community $ip PowerNet-MIB::sPDUOutletCtl.$1)
currentState="${currentState: -1}"

# figure out the suffix ...

sfx='Off'
[[ "${currentState}" = "2" ]] && sfx='On'

# now make the snmpset call
snmpset -v 1 -c "${community}" "${ip}" PowerNet-MIB::sPDUOutletCtl.$1 i outlet"${sfx}"
```

Comment: I thought the question was about combining the `smtpget` with the line that gets the last character.

Comment: ahhh, missed that twist; I was (obviously) looking at how to collapse the current `if/then/else` into a single `if` test

Comment: The question is confusing about what he really wants.